# How to encode and decode plotly images in Python

Tags: python-3.x, image, plotly, encode

I am trying to encode and decode a figure generated using python plotly ,please help me with the codes to do it.

For matplotlib images following this code:

```
fig = io.BytesIO()
fig.savefig(fig, format='png', bbox_inches='tight')
fig.seek(0)
encoded = base64.b64encode(fig.getvalue())
```

But for plotly images giving error like: `Plotly AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'savefig'`

What is the alternate here

Comment: do you really mean "as image".  `to_dict()` encodes a figure as a dict,  that can be serialised as JSON.  Obviously this is also simple to decode.  Decoding a **png** etc is not going to be reliable - you will have lost all the data and layout instructions

Comment: @RobRaymond Thanks for the answer ,updated question with few more details